# SQL Count with Different Condition on single Query

Tags: sql

I have a query like:

```
SELECT          a.EmployeeId,
                count(a.JobStatusId) cTotOut
FROM            ActivityRecord a
where           a.jobstatusid <> 5
GROUP BY        a.EmployeeId

SELECT          a.EmployeeId,
                count(a.JobStatusId) cTotHis
FROM            ActivityRecord a
where           a.jobstatusid = 5
GROUP BY        a.EmployeeId
```

The result on my PC is like:

[image]

I want the queries above become a single query and become something like:

```
---------------------------------------
EmployeeId       cTotOut       cTotHis
---------------------------------------
A                7             5
B                5             7
C                4             8
```

I have a question:
Is it possible with two different condition into a single query?

Please advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    EmployeeId,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN jobstatusid <> 5 THEN 1 END) AS cTotOut,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN jobstatusid = 5  THEN 1 END) AS cTotHis
FROM ActivityRecord
GROUP BY EmployeeId;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. This one is correct! Do you have any idea for Linq syntax?

Comment: @Haminteu I don't use LINQ very often, so off the top of my head, no, I don't know how to express conditional aggregation in a LINQ query.

Comment: just remove the linq question. I found it. Thanks a lot anyway. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT          a.EmployeeId,
            SUM(
             CASE
               WHEN a.JobStatusId<>5 THEN 1
               ELSE 0 END) cTotOut,
           SUM(
             CASE
               WHEN a.JobStatusId=5 THEN 1
               ELSE 0 END)cTotHis
  FROM            ActivityRecord a
  GROUP BY        a.EmployeeId
```

You can try this. Sorry, about LinQ I know nothing, if it is possible and how